# merge the specific row in from two dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have df like this

df1:

```
   Name      A        B      C
            a  b    r  t   y   U
0  xyz      1  2    3  4   3   4
1  abc      3  5    4  7   7   8
2  pqr      2  4    4  5   4   6
```

df2:

```
   Name      A          B        C
            a    b    r    t   y    U
0  xyz      Nan Nan  Nan  Nan  Nan Nan
1  abc      2    4    5  7     7   9
2  pqr      Nan Nan  Nan  Nan  Nan Nan
```

i want df like this

```
    Name      A          B        C
            a    b    r    t    y    U
0  xyz      Nan Nan  Nan  Nan   Nan Nan
1  abc      5    9    9   14    14  17
2  pqr      Nan Nan  Nan  Nan   Nan Nan
```

basically i want the sum of abc row only

Comment: If `Name` is not index, set it as index, then `df1 + df2` should do it.

Comment: Okay then set name as a index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check what is columns names, obviously it is tuple `('Name', '')` here, so set to `index` and then `sum` it:

```
print (df1.columns.tolist())
print (df2.columns.tolist())

df1 = df1.set_index([('Name', '')])
df2 = df2.set_index([('Name', '')])

#set by position
#df1 = df1.set_index([df1.columns[0]])
#df2 = df2.set_index([df2.columns[0]])

df = df1.add(df2)
```

Or:

```
df = df1 + df2
```